# How would i edit/update values in a dynamic table using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a program that accepts inputs from a user by entering them into a modal, after doing so, the user clicks a button which adds all the inputs to their respective columns within the tables row. The user is allowed to add as many rows as they need with varying information. The inputs are as follows: An image via an input of type file, as well as two text inputs, one for their name and another for their surname.

Alongside the inputs displayed within the row, i have created an edit and delete button. The focus for this question will be on the edit button. Once pressed, the edit button needs to bring up an update modal with the same fields as the original adding modal. The user should be able to change/update the information within all 3 inputs, and this should dynamically update the row for which the edit button had been pressed (each row has its own edit button).

How would i go about doing this? My jQuery code is as follows:

```
//add data
$("#addToTable").click(function() {

  var imageLocation = $("#insertImage").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, "images/");

  counter++;

  $("#container table").append(
    $('<tr id="' + counter + '">')


    //below is the image input
    .append($('<td class="align-middle">').html("<img src=" + imageLocation + " class='image' data-toggle='popover'" + "data-img=" + imageLocation + ">").on("mouseover", function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
        content: function() {
          return '<img class="img-fluid" src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />';
        },
        title: 'Enlarged Image'
      })
    }))
    .append($('<td class="align-middle">').html($('#addName').val())) //the name input

    .append($('<td class="align-middle">').html($('#addSurname').val())) //the surname input

    .append($('<td class="align-middle">').html("<i class='fas fa-user-edit faa-shake animated-hover' id='pencilIcon'></i></button>").on("click", function() {
      $('#updateDataOnTable').modal("toggle"); // this brings up the update modal once the edit button has been pressed.
    }))

    .append($('<td class="align-middle">').html("<i class='fas fa-dumpster faa-shake animated-hover' id='dumpsterIcon'></i>").on("click", function() {
      let deleteRow = this;
      $('#modalDelete').modal("toggle");

      $('#no').on("click", function() {
        $('#modalDelete').modal("toggle");
        deleteRow = "";
      })

      $('#yes').on("click", function() {
        $(deleteRow).parents("tr").remove();
        $('#modalDelete').modal("toggle");
      })
    }))

  )
  formClear(); //clears the inputs

});
```

As it stands, the program only brings up the update modal (HTML code shown below):

```
  <!-- Update Modal -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="updateDataOnTable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="website" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Update Table</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="updateImage">Insert Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" name="insertImage" id="updateImage" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" aria-describedby="inputHelp">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="updateName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateName">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="updateSurname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="updateSurname">
              </div>
            </form>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="updateTable" value=id>Update</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)